# How to fit a set of data with two different functions

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a set of data with a step function. But it doesn't work. To make it simple, here is what I am trying to do.

I have a set of data. From x=0 to x=y, the curve follows a x^2. From x=y to x=100, it is 0.

The idea is to find the best fit so that I have a value for y. It doesn't work because it says: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 710 input values to the 323 output values where the mask is true.

Here is my code. I have 710 values in each column.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('myfile.txt',delimiter='\t')
xdata = data[:,0]
ydata = data[:,1]
x = np.linspace(0,230,710)

def func(x,a,y):
    c=np.zeros(710)
    c[x<y] = a*(x-y)**2
    c[x>y] = 0
    return c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0 = [0.0001,50])

print a
print t
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The exception you got is because of `c[x<y] = a*(x-y)**2`. left side has 323 values and right side has 710 values. This is because of the condition `x < y` that should be also on the right side:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

a = 5
y = 47

xdata = np.linspace(0, 100, 710)
ydata = a*xdata**2
ydata[xdata > y] = 0

def func(x, a, y):
    c = np.zeros(710)
    c[x < y] = a*(x[x < y]**2)
    c[x >= y] = 0
    return c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0 = [6, 46.5])

print popt
```